# Instructions for "One Click" deploy of Android App for Eclipse Newbie?

Tags: android, deployment

Just curious if anyone has a step by step tutorial on how to set up Eclipse (or a batch file) for "One Click" deployment of an Android app. Automating such tasks like removing the debuggable setting from the project manifest, exporting the unsigned APK and signing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Ant to build, sign, etc. If `ant release` is not enough, just customize the script to do what you need. There is also some (unofficial) support for Maven.

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/building/building-cmdline.html

Comment: Has nobody developed a plugin or something for Eclipse? Surely it's a wanted feature. I can't sum up how many hours I've wasted in total going through the tedious clicks and password entries, switching back and forth between multiple keys for multiple markets...

Comment: @pilcrowpipe true. Plus I occasionally get errors after exporting, the apk file turns out to be corrupt. So I manually try the apk file to check if it is working.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way (according to me) is to use the Android export-wizard.

> Right click on your project->Android tools->Export Signed Application
>   Package.

(You'll still have to fix your settings -like removing debuggable- manually though).